# what is the area of circle with out countable points in it?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, number-theory

Thank you all.
Area  of circle equals 22/7 * r^2.
The area of it with out the circumference of a circle is the same close circle.
What is the area if i omit countable points from it?

Comment: Did you just assume $\pi=\frac{22}7$?

Comment: That approximation to $\pi$ will have a much larger effect on the area that omitting a countable number of points.  In fact, you could omit an uncountable number of points with less effect.

Comment: Fun fact, $\pi = 22/7$ is what the ancient Chinese used.

Comment: I recall a prof of computer science recounting  that when he was once working outside of a university, a colleague had hard-coded $3.14$ for the value of $\pi$ in  a loop and  didn't know why his results were bad.

Answer (score 3):

If you omit a set of $2$-dimensional Lebesgue measure $0$, then you also get the same area ($\pi r^2$).

Since a set of countable points is of measure $0$, the area remains the same.